# How Insert a Select statement value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert a `SELECT` statement value. I tried doing this:

```
INSERT INTO transactiondetails 
VALUES (SELECT TOP 1
            transactionid
        FROM     
            transactions
        ORDER BY 
            desc, '1', '2',)
```

Comment: what is the meaning "order by desc, .1"?

Comment: The SELECT Statement just gets the last TransactionID from the Transactions table. I'm trying to get that value and insert into the TransactionDetails table along with '1' and '2'

Comment: check my answer too.

Comment: **RTFM!!** - here's the [official MSDN docs on the `INSERT` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) which clearly explains all the various options you have - **consult it first** before asking here on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `TransactionDetails` table has 3 columns, perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
Insert Into TransactionDetails
Select Top 1 TransactionId, 1, 2
From Transactions 
Order By TransactionId Desc
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: since the data in a relational table really isn't sorted by default, the `ORDER BY` is pretty pointless in this select statement. It doesn't hurt - but it doesn't do anything beneficial, either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO TransactionDetails(field1,field2,field3)
         SELECT TOP 1 TransactionID,'1','2' FROM Transactions ORDER BY TransactionID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

if 1 and 2 is static value than you can do like this...

```
INSERT INTO TransactionDetails
VALUES (col1,col2,col3)                  
 SELECT TOP 1 TransactionID,1,2 FROM Transactions ORDER BY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this also.

```
;with CTE
 as(     
        SELECT  
            TOP 1 transactionid as transactionid, 
            '1' as '1',
            '2' as '2'
        FROM     transactions
        ORDER BY column1 desc  --you need to give columnname
    )

 INSERT into transactiondetails 

 SELECT
        CTE.transactionid,
        CTE.1,
        CTE.2       
 from CTE
```